# django packages app names clash

Tags: django, django-apps, django-allauth

My django project has a local app named 'accounts' that manages User accounts. It has live and populated db tables that start with accounts_. It also has a `urls.py` entry:

```
(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
```

Now, I want to use django-allauth to support OpenId. However, I noticed that there is an app name clash since allauth also uses `accounts` to create db tables starting with accounts_ and asks urls.py to contain:

```
(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

What is the best way to solve this app name conflict?

Comment: Unless there are conflicting targets, both the app urls could work with each other .

Comment: @karthikr, how could they create db tables? Currently I get `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "django_content_type_pkey"` error. which is happening because django-allauth is trying to create db tables starting with accounts_ which already exist because of my accounts app.

Comment: Oh.. I thought the conflicts are only with the urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [`db_table` to Meta](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table):

```
class Accounts(models.Model):
    # ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'my_accounts'
```

Regarding the URL's. Can't you use both? I.e:

```
(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

Comment: `accounts` is not a class but an app name. So, I used to rename all tables under the accounts app. This is giving me a Database Internal Error in auth_permission but that is probably orthogonal to this question. Thank you.